# prevent the app from closing

Tags: ios, ipad, kiosk-mode

Recently i visited a restaurant and they use iPad for ordering. When i tried to close the app by pressing the home button it did not close. Rather it blinked (may be went to background and came up again i don't know). then i was prompted for admin password.

But when i searched [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252526/how-to-prevent-an-iphone-app-from-closing-until-all-activity-is-done) most answers suggest that it is not possible. As per my understanding i can use development certificate and implement this in my personal device. May be the restaurant might have also done that.

Can someone shed some light on how to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 4):

You can put an iPad into Kiosk mode.

This will essentially lock it into a particular app with a pass key required to do anything else.

http://www.ipadenclosures.com/blog/posts/your-ipad-into-a-kiosk

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with objective-c. It's a feature on iPhones and iPads called Guided Access: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5509?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do it - One of the simplest is [through guided access](http://www.webascender.com/Blog/ID/447/How-to-Setup-Kiosk-Mode-Lock-Your-iPad-to-Just-One-App#.UzKf0NyzvDM)

Another, even more secure, is through [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12) - When you supervise a device you can lock it to one app and disable the controls just as with the guided access method. With this method you can supervise multiple devices and apply standard configurations quickly by simply plugging them into your Mac's USB port.